# Problem is Mine

Tags: pronouns, possessives, modifiers

I have a question about a phrase:

> [link](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/golf-devil-ball-golf/rory-mcilroy-calls-off-his-engagement-to-caroline-wozniacki-after-sending-out-wedding-invites-144544611.html)
>   The problem is ***mine***.

How is this different from the following:

"The problem is ***me***".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your examples is whether they're **possessive**:

```
  The problem is [me     ]         ＝  The problem is me.
  The problem is [me + 's]         ＝  The problem is mine.
```

In the first sentence, you are the problem.  In the second sentence, the problem belongs to you.

---

You usually make the possessive by adding *'s* to words:

```
  The problem is [Sam + 's] egg    ＝  The problem is Sam's egg.
  The problem is [Sam + 's]        ＝  The problem is Sam's.
```

But pronouns are special.  When you try to add *'s* to them, you get special forms.  In the case of *me*, there are two forms, *my* and *mine*:

```
  The problem is [me + 's] egg     ＝  The problem is my egg.
  The problem is [me + 's]         ＝  The problem is mine.
```

In the first sentence, the egg belongs to you, and that egg is the problem.  In the second sentence, the problem belongs to you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is mine ~ the problem belongs to you **OVER** The problem is me ~ you are the problem!

*mine* is a pronoun which means *belonging to me.* and pronoun *me* is an objective form of *I.*

Check the example to make it clear:

> *Don't you bother about it, the problem is mine.* 
>    *I know, between Jane and you, I'm the problem. Don't worry, I'll leave the city soon.*

Comment: +1 But in PDE it might be more accurate to describe *me* as the **base** form, with *I* as a marked subjective form.

Comment: @StoneyB I remember it that way as I learned it for the question *me* or *I* with an answer that describes the difference between 'you' as an object or subject.

Comment: So did I; but the brute fact is that in use, *me/us/him/her/them* are the 'default' forms in any context which is not explicitly subjective. "Who wants this?" -"Me!" ... "Who did this?" ... "Him and her."